# How to run Angularcli project with https

Tags: angular-cli

As of now with angular cli (beta 28), NG development server runs with defaultly HTTP. If we want to run with HTTPS. we need to do something else..

Comment: Got it!!!.

After setting up project with angular cli (beta 28).
we need to install browser-sync by using command..
NPM install browser-sync.
after installing go to folder ...
../node_modules/browser-sync/lib/serve/certs
copy the above folder and paste at "src" folder level and name it as (cert) in my case.

And made some changes to package.json as shown below
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key certs/server.key --ssl-cert ssl/server.crt --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453112/how-to-run-angular-with-https-which-by-default-run-with-http/54453113#54453113