# How to run Angular e2e with SSL enabled?

Tags: angular, selenium, ssl, protractor, angular-cli

I have a pretty simple Angular sample project, with some end to end tests. I'm testing OAuth2 and OIDC flows in my end to end tests, and browsers behave quite differently with or without SSL/TLS enabled. So I'd like to run my end to end tests with SSL turned on locally too.

I now run my tests with the Angular CLI like this:

```
ng e2e
```

I tried to run it like this:

```
ng e2e --ssl=true
```

Although the `--ssl=true` option does work for `ng serve`, it does *not* work for `ng e2e` giving me:

> Unknown option: '--ssl'

**Is there a way or workaround to make the Angular CLI based Protractor / Selenium tests run with SSL?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453112/how-to-run-angular-with-https-which-by-default-run-with-http I think this can help you.

Comment: You can find the answer on <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453112/how-to-run-angular-with-https-which-by-default-run-with-http">Here</a>

Comment: That question is about _running_ with SSL. I've tried it nonetheless, and it got me 1 step further, but I still get stuck. Have updated the question to reflect this new info. EDIT: It helped me find a final answer, will share! Tyvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can adapt [the solution for *running* `ng` with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453112/how-to-run-angular-with-https-which-by-default-run-with-http) to make it work for both local and CI based running. Steps by step:

Add `ssl/certificate.cnf`:

```conf
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
x509_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C = NL
O = My Organisation
emailAddress = dummy@example.org
CN = localhost

[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

Generate a `.cert` file with:

```bash
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout ssl/localhost.key -days 3560 -out ssl/localhost.crt -config ssl/certificate.cn
```

Update the `serve` in `angular.json` to be:

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "ssl": true,
    "sslKey": "ssl/localhost.key",
    "sslCert": "ssl/localhost.crt",
    "browserTarget": "sample-auth-guards:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "sample-auth-guards:build:production"
    }
  }
},
```

Then add `acceptInsecureCerts` to your `protractor.conf.js` file's `capabilities` section, which will then look like this:

```js
capabilities: {
  acceptInsecureCerts: true, // <<<<< Add this!
  browserName: 'chrome'
},
```

And then run `ng e2e`. It should run your application with SSL, and the `e2e` tests should use this server too. The protractor conf will allow you to skip the "Insecure Cert" warning that Chrome gives you normally.

For reference, I use a `protractor-ci.conf.js` file for GitHub Actions running, that tweaks things a bit. It looks like this:

```js
const config = require('./protractor.conf').config;

config.capabilities = {
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      '--headless',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-gpu',
    ],
  },
};

exports.config = config;
```

This also makes the browser *headless* in addition to accepting insecure certificates.

See [this in action in my full repository](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards).